# Why does my Oracle SQLPlus script file produce no output but the interactive query does?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Using Oracle sqlplus, I attempt to run a script file like this:

```
sqlplus SVC_VISN_RRDW/********@usrrsit @c:\temp\SQLPlusToCSV.sql
```

The script file looks like this:

```
set colsep ,
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 32767
set numwidth 22
set termout off
spool R:\temp\usccplan.csv
SELECT CAST (UNIQ_ID AS VARCHAR2 (50))           AS PlanUniqueID,
       CAST (SRC_CD AS VARCHAR2 (5))             AS PlanSourceSystem,
       CAST (PLAN_ID AS VARCHAR2 (30))           AS PlanID,
       CAST (PLAN_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (30))         AS PlanType,
       CAST (RT_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (10))           AS RateType,
       CAST (INDX_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (10))         AS IndexType,
       CAST (SPRD_TO_INDX AS NUMBER (22, 7))     AS Spread,
       CAST (CUST_RT AS NUMBER (22, 7))          AS CustomerRate,
       CAST (CURR_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS PlanCurrentBalance,
       CAST (AVG_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))          AS AverageBalance,
       CAST (CYC_END_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))      AS CycleEndBalance,
       CAST (RVLV_AMT AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS RevolvingAmount,
       CAST (INT_INCM AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS InterestIncome,
       CAST (ACT_CUR_PER AS NUMBER (1))          AS ActiveInLastYear,
       TO_CHAR (AS_OF_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')          AS AsOfDate,
       TO_CHAR (CREATE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')         AS CreateDate,
       CAST (RUN_ID AS INT)                      AS RunID,
       TO_CHAR (AUDIT_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')          AS AuditDate
  FROM VISN_EXP.V_IHCVSN_CR_CARD_PLAN_DTL
WHERE AS_OF_DT = to_date('2019-01-04','yyyy-mm-dd')
spool off
```

When I run the command, it runs in seconds but does not write to the CSV file:

```
PS R:\> sqlplus SVC_VISN_RRDW/********@usrrsit @c:\temp\SQLPlusToCSV.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Apr 21 11:23:48 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Apr 21 2021 11:22:02 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

 22
SQL>
```

However, if I copy the same query and paste it into the same sqlplus session, it produces output (would be millions of rows if I didn't limit it):

```
SQL> SELECT CAST (UNIQ_ID AS VARCHAR2 (50))           AS PlanUniqueID,
  2         CAST (SRC_CD AS VARCHAR2 (5))             AS PlanSourceSystem,
  3         CAST (PLAN_ID AS VARCHAR2 (30))           AS PlanID,
  4         CAST (PLAN_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (30))         AS PlanType,
  5         CAST (RT_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (10))           AS RateType,
  6         CAST (INDX_TYPE AS VARCHAR2 (10))         AS IndexType,
  7         CAST (SPRD_TO_INDX AS NUMBER (22, 7))     AS Spread,
  8         CAST (CUST_RT AS NUMBER (22, 7))          AS CustomerRate,
  9         CAST (CURR_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS PlanCurrentBalance,
 10         CAST (AVG_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))          AS AverageBalance,
 11         CAST (CYC_END_BAL AS NUMBER (22, 2))      AS CycleEndBalance,
 12         CAST (RVLV_AMT AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS RevolvingAmount,
 13         CAST (INT_INCM AS NUMBER (22, 2))         AS InterestIncome,
 14         CAST (ACT_CUR_PER AS NUMBER (1))          AS ActiveInLastYear,
 15         TO_CHAR (AS_OF_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')          AS AsOfDate,
 16         TO_CHAR (CREATE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')         AS CreateDate,
 17         CAST (RUN_ID AS INT)                      AS RunID,
 18         TO_CHAR (AUDIT_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')          AS AuditDate
 19    FROM VISN_EXP.V_IHCVSN_CR_CARD_PLAN_DTL
 20  WHERE AS_OF_DT = to_date('2019-01-04','yyyy-mm-dd')
 21  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
RD412312855                                       ,FVP  ,1-3                           ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,                     0,                 54.71,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324596                                       ,FVP  ,1-2                           ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,                     0,                  9.57,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412306019                                       ,FVP  ,1-2                           ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,                     0,                  8.12,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324445                                       ,FVP  ,52-2                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                    15,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324465                                       ,FVP  ,52-5                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                    35,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324473                                       ,FVP  ,52-2                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                    35,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324498                                       ,FVP  ,52-2                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                     5,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324503                                       ,FVP  ,52-5                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                    35,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412324517                                       ,FVP  ,52-2                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                     0,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05

RD412314135                                       ,FVP  ,52-2                          ,Standard              ,Fixed
 ,          ,                     0,              .0000001,                 36.61,                  ,                  ,
                     0,                     0,                     0,2019-01-04,2019-01-05,                -1,2019-01-05


10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong but cannot spot it.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: The query in your script is missing a semi colon at the end of it; if you add that (at the end of the line before the `spool off` command), does it start working?

Comment: LOL!  Totally missed that.  Appreciate the second set of eyes on it.  If you publish this as an answer I'll mark it as the solution and you can get the creds!